# Minimal (write) ABAC Policy for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, policy, abac

I am using Kubernetes 1.4.5 and installed a HA cluster from scratch (with each component in the System instead of containers)

In order to enhance security, each component has a single certificate to connect against the apiserver(s). To define the permissions, I use the [ABAC](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/) plugin. I do not bother with the read permissions but want to ensure that the write permissions are only enabled for the modules which are in charge for "something".

I did not find any documentation about which component needs at least which permissions to. I started to configure, look for errors and start over.

I started with [the tls tutorial from Kelsey Hightower](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/docker-kubernetes-tls-guide) and "failed forward".

This is what I have so far

```
{"user":"system:logging"}
{"user":"system:monitoring"}
{"user":"system:serviceaccount:default:default"}
{"user":"system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default"}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"nagios", "namespace": "*", "resource": "*", "apiGroup": "*", "nonResourcePath": "*", "readonly": true }}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"kubelet", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "*", "readonly": true}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"kubelet", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "nodes"}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"kubelet", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "pods"}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"kubelet", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "events"}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"proxy", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "*", "readonly": true}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"proxy", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "events"}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"scheduler", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "*", "readonly": true}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"scheduler", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "endpoints"}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"scheduler", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "bindings"}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"scheduler", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "events"}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"controller_manager", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "*","nonResourcePath": "*", "readonly": true}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"controller_manager", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "events"}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"controller_manager", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "endpoints"}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"controller_manager", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "deployments"}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"controller_manager", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "serviceaccounts"}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"controller_manager", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "secrets"}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"controller_manager", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "replicasets"}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"controller_manager", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "pods"}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"controller_manager", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "replicationcontrollers"}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"controller_manager", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "persistentvolumes"}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"controller_manager", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "persistentvolumeclaims"}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"controller_manager", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "statefulsets"}}
```

Does anyone know if I am missing something?

[UPDATE]
I found that only defining the spec was not ok as the controller manager gets into trouble. So I updated the config with the full lines.

Comment: What about kube-dns and kubelet? You also have resources missing for controller_manager, example: namespaces, services, configmaps, ingress, etc.

Comment: kube-dns uses the serviceaccount to connect with the api as it runs inside the api. The above mentioned configuration is a little outdated as I have added some persmissions. The question is if the controller_manager needs writeable permissions on this items. It was granted full read-only permissions, so only write object need to be defined. As said, the configuration was a "fail-forward" attemp as I was not able to find any information about the needed minimum.